# Python Show financial Month and Year in python using date

Tags: python

How to show financial Month and Year in python using date.

- if I enter the date 2016-10-01 it must show the finance year April 2016 to March 2017
- if I enter the date 2017-05-01 it must show the finance year April 2017 to March 2018
- if I enter the date 2017-08-01 it must show the finance year April 2017 to March 2018

Guys please help me ...Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Take a look at [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module. You need [date.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function

Comment: I can take date using datetime module, But I don't have an idea for writing an algorithm form this, that's why I asked for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

#function take input of the datestring like 2017-05-01
def get_financial_year(datestring):
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            #initialize the current year
            year_of_date=date.year
            #initialize the current financial year start date
            financial_year_start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(year_of_date)+"-04-01","%Y-%m-%d").date()
            if date<financial_year_start_date:
                    return 'April, '+ str(financial_year_start_date.year-1)+' to March, '+ str(financial_year_start_date.year)
            else:
                    return 'April, '+ str(financial_year_start_date.year)+' to March, '+ str(financial_year_start_date.year+1)
```

**Output**

```
get_financial_year("2017-05-01") : April, 2017 to March, 2018
```

Comment: Thank you for this method.. which works perfect